# grid view hidden after click on page number index on grid view?

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, c#-4.0, webforms

I work on sp.net web form I face issue grid view Hidden after click on page number on grid view .

so when click search button data display success with pagination.

**issue happen when try to navigate or click on any page on grid view control**  .

**grid view hidden and not display when click to any page number .**

why this happen and how to solve this issue .

```
protected void grdData_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            
            GridViewSearchData.DataSource = GetDataForSearch(dropBranches.SelectedItem.Value);
            GridViewSearchData.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            GridViewSearchData.DataBind();
             
        }


 public void BindGrdiview()
        {
            DataTable dt=new DataTable();

            dt = GetDataForSearch(dropBranches.SelectedItem.Value);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridViewSearchData.DataSource = dt;
                GridViewSearchData.DataBind();

              

            }
        }
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindGrdiview();
            }
         }
protected void grdData_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            
            GridViewSearchData.DataSource = GetDataForSearch(dropBranches.SelectedItem.Value);
            GridViewSearchData.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            GridViewSearchData.DataBind();
             
        }
    public DataTable GetDataForSearch(string BranchId)
        {
            string response = string.Empty;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "select datelogged AS EntredDatetime, Doc_type AS OrderType,Doc_number as OrderNo, Printer_name, [dbo].[tbl_Branch].vBranchDesc AS BranchCode,case when Status=0 then 'Waiting for PDF' when Status=1 then 'Waiting for Printing' when Status=2 then 'Printed' when Status in (8,9) then 'Error in PDF generation' Else 'Error in Printing' end as   Status, id from Print_Report  where BranchID=@BranchCode";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 50000;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchCode", BranchId);
              
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                sda.Fill(dt);
             
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
            }
            return dt;
}
```

aspx page grid view control

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSearchData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#172b4d"   AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="grdData_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="10">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BranchCode" HeaderText="BranchCode" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderNo" HeaderText="OrderNo" ItemStyle-Width="120px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderType" HeaderText="OrderType" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Printer_name" HeaderText="Printer_name" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="EntredDatetime" HeaderText="EntredDatetime" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  />                            
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden"  />
     
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I solved my issue nothing wrong on code above thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved  issue , I found class CSS hidden div contain grid view so I remove it And it working .

before issues done it like that :

```
    GridViewSearchData.DataSource = dt;
    GridViewSearchData.DataBind();
    PSline.Attributes.Add("class");
```

after solve issue it like that :

```
    GridViewSearchData.DataSource = dt;
    GridViewSearchData.DataBind();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).